# Gradle sync every time if we add the new xml layout

Tags: android

When I add the new xml layout gradle sync starts.

How to we stop this sync for each time ?

Note: I tried google,official sites and SO no answer found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be casued by

```
 dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

in `build.gradle` script.

It ia trying to generate `databinding` class for `XML` layout